# How to work without xmp tag

Tags: javascript, html, tags, xmp

I've recently learn about the use of *xmp* tag, that it is deprecated, and a lot of people says to use *pre*, or to translate special characters with `&lt;`, `&gt;`, etc.

... but those solutions are not good in my case.

Actually, i would like to put content in a webpage, and that this content was not interpreted until i copy it, with JavaScript, into an other container.

For now i've found only one solution, which is not realy clean :

```
<div id="myContent" class="hidden">
    <!--MyContent-->
</div>
```

Then, via Javascript, i parse the content to remove the comment html tags.

Have you found better solutions to do that?

Comment: Why are "those solutions not good" in your case?

Comment: Because when i will paste the content with javascript, the special characters will make the tag are not interpreted by the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use xml/html data islands to store arbitrary data in your html. The following samples show some variations:

1. xml data
2. html data
3. arbitrary text
4. arbitrary text represented as a xml cdata section

The `script` tgas can be accessed from javascript and universal attributes like `id` may be added to simplify access.

```
<!-- xml -->
<script type="text/xml">
    <data>
        <!-- whatever -->
    </data>
</script>

<!-- html -->
<script type="text/html">
    <a href="http://example.com">example.com</a>
</script>

<!-- plain text -->
<script type="text/plain">
    whatever
</script>

<!-- plain text in an xml cdata section (text mustn't contain ']]>') -->
<script type="text/xml">
    <plain><![CDATA[...whatever...]]></plain>
</script>
```

There is an [article on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Using_XML_Data_Islands_in_Mozilla) discussing the technique.

There used to be the option to place `xml` tags in html documents. This is no longer supported by IE as of IE10.